# Why the while loop is not working in this code?

Tags: python

I want to print the following pattern but the while loop for length is not running. When i run the code it only prints one triangle
Below the code there is expected output and actual output :

```
height = int(input("Enter height ? "))
length = int(input("Enter length ? "))
spaces  = height-1
spaces2 = 0
while length > 0:
    for n in range(height):
        for i in range(spaces):
            print(' ',end="")
        print('/',end="")
        for j in range(spaces2):
            print(' ',end="")
        print('\\',end="")
        for k in range(spaces):
            print(' ', end="")
        print('')
        height-=1
        spaces-=1
        spaces2+=2
    length-=1
```

Expected Output :

height = 5
length = 3

```
    /\        /\        /\        
   /  \      /  \      /  \      
  /    \    /    \    /    \    
 /      \  /      \  /      \  
/        \/        \/        \
```

Output when the code ran :

height = 5
length = 3

```
    /\           
   /  \          
  /    \       
 /      \   
/        \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop is working. But the first time through the `while` loop your code changes the values of `height`, `spaces2`, and `spaces`. The second time through the `while` loop, these values are all zero so the `for` loops do nothing. To show that, add the line `print(length)` just below the line `length -= 1`. You will see 3 iterations of the `while` loop reported.

Answer (score 0):

here the reason is that the first for loop change the height variable to zero, so this for and the other for in the second iterations of while loop don't work(iterate for zero time)

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was already answered, posting another solution (as I played a bit with the problem, and therefore taking a slightly different approach).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def _triangle(height, bk_char=chr(0x20)):
    for i in range(height):
        yield "".join([bk_char * (height - i - 1), '/', bk_char * (2 * i), '\\', bk_char * (height - i - 1)])


def triangles(height, count):
    for line in _triangle(height):
        yield line * count

def main():
    print("\n".join(triangles(7, 5)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("Done.")
```

**Notes**:

- Generators are used
- *_triangle*:

  1. Generates string lines instead of just printing them
  2. For each line, it also includes the "invisible" *SPACE* *char*s that come after the right edge (so at the end, it generates a rectangle that contains (boxes) the triangle)
- *triangles*:

  - Simply multiplies the triangle horizontally (line by line). This is possible because of last bullet's ***#2.*** item

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055810531]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>       /\            /\            /\            /\            /\
>      /  \          /  \          /  \          /  \          /  \
>     /    \        /    \        /    \        /    \        /    \
>    /      \      /      \      /      \      /      \      /      \
>   /        \    /        \    /        \    /        \    /        \
>  /          \  /          \  /          \  /          \  /          \
> /            \/            \/            \/            \/            \
> Done.
> ```